# How to firewall qemu/kvm guest in host machine?

Tags: ip, firewall, qemu

I have a `qemu` guest with following network topology:

```
Internet <-> eth1.96[bridge]tap96 <-> eth0[guest]
```

I need to allow access to guest machine only from one specific /24 network and I can't configure firewall in guest so I see only three possible locations for firewall:

1. INPUT chain of eth1
2. INPUT chain of eth1.96
3. OUTPUT chain of tap96

Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: What OS is running on the host? Linux?

Comment: `libvirt` allows the (`vlan`) tagging of ethernet packages, maybe that can help? [libvirt manual](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#elementVlanTag)